# C# reflection to return all properties in a class whose Type implements a specific interface

Tags: c#

I am trying to use reflection to return all properties in a class whose Type implements the `IMyInterface` interface.

Here is a simple console app that shows where I am and isolates the issue at hand...

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var parent = new Parent();

            parent.GetPropertiesThatImplementIMyInterface();
        }
    }

    public interface IMyInterface { }

    public class A : IMyInterface { }

    public class B { }

    public class Parent
    {
        public A A { get; set; }
        public B B { get; set; }

        public void GetPropertiesThatImplementIMyInterface()
        {
            var props = this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IMyInterface)));

            Debug.WriteLine(props.Count());
        }
    }
}
```

The `Debug.WriteLine` returns a count of 0 in the `GetPropertiesThatImplementIMyInterface` method call.  It should return a count of 1 for the `A` property.  How can this code be changed to make it do what I need?

Comment: I think you have it backwards?  `typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType)`?

Comment: Yep that was it, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=netframework-4.8) of `Type.IsAssignableFrom` says:

> Determines whether an instance of a specified type can be assigned to a variable of the current type.

So an expression like

```
typeof(A).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(B))
```

where `A` and `B` are reference types, actually checks whether this will compile (without a conversion):

```
A a = someB;
```

In your case, you want to check whether the property could be assigned to `IMyInterface`, so:

```
IMyInterface x = someProperty;
```

Therefore, you need:

```
typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType)
```

Not the other way around.

Comment: How I wish that method was called something else. Maybe it's just me, but that scrambles my brain and I can't figure out which order they go in. I always end up writing a test. I should create a DotNetFiddle or a self-answered question and save a link to it.

Comment: @ScottHannen I agree, it's a very un-intuitive function.  I think it helps to create an extension method `IsAssignableTo` and use that instead.  Autofac provides such a function.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reversing the check to fit this?

```
typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType)
```